# How to use non-ESRI tiles inside Arc Online

Tags: arcgis-online-basemaps

This link now appears to be outdated.  [LINK](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/04/01/using-stamen-and-mapbox-tilesets-as-basemaps-in-arcgis-com/)

Is there another way to display other tiles as basemaps with the current configuration?

Here's the link I'm trying to use:  http://b.tile.stamen.com/watercolor/12/655/1582.jpg

Comment: Can you post a url to the tiles you're attempting to use?

Comment: The UI has changes a bit since the blog post, but same method still works.

Comment: I updated with the new link.  In the link that shows you how to do it, it doesn't have an area for subdomains.